# Adding a column to datatables framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I been doing some research on the internet and I haven't found anything yet. Simple question here, using [datables](https://www.datatables.net/), can I add a column based on calculations from different columns? Thanks

Edit.
NVM, I think I got doing this

```
aoColumns: [

         { mData: 'column1' },
         { mData: 'column2' },

         { mRender: function(data, type, row){
                 return (row.column1/ row.column2) 
         }}
```

Comment: That syntax you're using is the old (pre 1.10) version of datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The simplest way to do this is to use `columnDefs` and `columns.render`. There are various examples on the `columns.render` help page (https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). If you find you can't achieve what you want with that, also check out the `columns` initialization property and the `columns.data` property.